# create a ruby class that returns a string when referenced

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

HTTParty's response object appears to return `#parsed_response` when referenced. For example:

```
response = HTTParty.get(some_url)
response                 # => { some: 'random', stuff: 'in here' }
response.parsed_response # => { some: 'random', stuff: 'in here' }
```

Also, if you check the class of `response` it's not a hash but a response object

```
response.class # => HTTParty::Response
```

This is useful because you can check other things on `response` like `response.code` and also very convenient to simply reference the response to get the `parsed_response`.

**How can I do something like this in a class of my own? But rather than return a hash when referencing the class I want it to return a string.**

Here's a specific example of what I want to do:

```
not_a_string = MyClass.new('hello', [1, 2, 3])
not_a_string        # => 'hello'
not_a_string.stuff  # => [1, 2, 3]
```

So in rspec a test should pass like so:

```
not_a_string = MyClass.new('hello', [1, 2, 3])
not_a_string.should == 'hello'  # passes
```

Comment: Do you want {:a => "b"} Hash to be returned as "{:a => "b"}" ?

Comment: Did you try inheritance from `String`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
class MyClass < String
  attr_reader :stuff

  def initialize(string, stuff)
    super string
    @stuff = stuff
  end
end
```

it works like this

```
irb(main):002:0> t = MyClass.new('hello', [1, 2, 3])
=> "hello"
irb(main):003:0> t.stuff
=> [1, 2, 3]
irb(main):004:0> t.class
=> MyClass
```

-- EDIT: improved solution --

this is much cleaner

```
class MyClass < Struct.new(:string, :stuff)
  def ==(other)
    string == other
  end

  def inspect
    string.inspect
  end
end
```

same output :)

```
irb(main):002:0> t = MyClass.new('hello', [1, 2, 3])
=> "hello"
irb(main):003:0> t.stuff
=> [1, 2, 3]
irb(main):004:0> t.class
=> MyClass
```

Comment: Oh, I guess the `inspect` solution is better, but thanks anyway!

Comment: hrm, your improved answer doesn't work for me. i get a struct when i create an instance of it.

Comment: uh? I am using ruby-2.0.0-p0, could it be that?

Comment: ah ok. I'm using 1.9. maybe that's what it is

Comment: Although it is pretty weird: it *is* working for me in ruby 1.9.3, see http://i.imgur.com/Q1fOHrU.png

Comment: ok, so the difference was that i was using pry. using irb it works just fine.

Comment: Anyhow, I like to use structs because they remove the typical boilerplate code, such as `attr_reader :string, :stuff` and `def initialize(string, stuff); @string = string; @stuff = stuff; end`. If you add just that it should work fine :)

Answer (score 1):

For your purposes it is sufficient to define `inspect` and `==`:

```
class Test
  def initialize(string)
    @string = string.to_s
  end

  def inspect
    @string.inspect
  end

  def ==(other)
    @string == other
  end
end

t = Test.new 'asd' #=> "asd"
t #=> "asd"
t == 'asd' #=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this is a neat feature :)
All you have to do is create an inspect method ;) here's an example :

```
class Greeter
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name.capitalize
  end

  def salute
    puts "Hello #{@name}!"
  end

  def inspect
    "hey"
  end
end


g = Greeter.new 'world'
g  # hey
```

Cheers !

Comment: i tried doing something similar with `to_s`. but notice it returns `hey` and not `"hey"`. it makes a difference because `g == "hey"` would be false which is not what i want. any idea how to get `"hey"` to be returned? this would actually be my preferred way to do it.